# twig date filter in macro loop prints wrong value

Tags: symfony, date, twig

I have a tree structured comment list. To display it I use a recursive twig macro:

```
{% macro comment_tree(tree) %}
{% import _self as macros %}
{% for node in tree %}
    <li>
        <div class="comment" id="comment{{ node.comment.id }}">
            <div class="text">
                {{ dump(node.comment.creationDate) }}
                <div class="datetime">{{ node.comment.creationDate | date("d.m.Y / H:m") }}</div>
                <p class="author">{{ node.comment.author }}</p>
                <p>{{ node.comment.text }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% if node.children is defined %}
            <ul>
                {{ macros.comment_tree(node.children) }}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

    </li>
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

`{{ node.comment.creationDate | date("d.m.Y / H:m") }}` now **always** prints the formatted date of the **first** comment. `{{ dump(node.comment.creationDate) }}` prints the correct value, all other comment attributes are correct as well.

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Did u verify each node has a different date to begin with?

Comment: yes. `{{ dump(node.comment.creationDate) }}` shows the correct date and `{{ node.comment.creationDate | date("d.m.Y / H:m") }}` one line later the wrong one